# Никак не мог установить библиотеку yandex-geocoder

Tags: python-3.6

Никак не могу установить библиотку yandex-geocoder. Выдает ошибку:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\alisher.yerikuly\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ALISHE~1.YER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9ucsc_9i\\yandex-geocoder\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ALISHE~1.YER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9ucsc_9i\\yandex-geocoder\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\ALISHE~1.YER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9ucsc_9i\yandex-geocoder\pip-egg-info'
     cwd: C:\Users\ALISHE~1.YER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9ucsc_9i\yandex-geocoder\
Complete output (9 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ALISHE~1.YER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9ucsc_9i\yandex-geocoder\setup.py", line 20, in <module>
    long_description=read("README.md"),
  File "C:\Users\ALISHE~1.YER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9ucsc_9i\yandex-geocoder\setup.py", line 8, in read
    return _f.read()
  File "c:\users\alisher.yerikuly\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 915: character maps to <undefined>
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

У меня питон 3.6

Comment: Права проверьте

Comment: + обновите setup tools `pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel`

Comment: @borodatych никак, та же ошибка